# How to Prove that the Eigenvalues of this Matrix are Zero, $\pm b$ for $b$ Real or Imaginary?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-polynomials

The matrix, $M$, is defined (below) in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials of a set.  For some special cases the matrix is nilpotent; for other (sufficiently small) cases the characteristic polynomial is 
$$
(-\lambda)^N +b^2 (-\lambda)^{N-2}
$$
for $b$ imaginary or real, so the eigenvalues are in $\{0^{\times 2}, \pm b \}$.  But how to prove that this is true for all values of $N$?

### Preliminaries

Consider the set of $N$ distinct, real values
$$
\{x_1, ... , x_N\}.
$$
The neighbors of $x_i$ are determined from the $i^{th}$ row of an $N\times N$ adjacency matrix $A$ that is subject to the constraints 
$$
A_{ij} \in \{ 0,1\}     \\
A_{ij}=A_{ji} \\
A_{ii}=1 \\
N^i \ge 3 
$$
where $N^i$ is the number of neighbors of $x_i$, given by 
$$N^i=\Sigma_{k=1}^N A_{ik}.$$

The indices of neighbors of $x_i$ are given by the set
$$\alpha^i = \{k \mid k \in \{1, \dots , N\} \wedge A_{ik}=1 \}.$$

### Defining the Matrix

Given a valid $A$, $M$ is an $N \times N$ matrix, the $i^{th}$ row of which obeys
$$
M_{i j} = 0  \;\;\;\;   j \notin \alpha^i  , \\
[
M_{i \alpha^i_1} 
\dots  
M_{i \alpha^i_{N^i}} 
]
\begin{bmatrix} 
x_{\alpha^i_1}^0 & ... & x_{\alpha^i_1}^{N^i-1} \\
 \vdots & & \vdots \\ 
 x_{\alpha^i_{N^i}}^0 & ... & x_{\alpha^i_{N^i}}^{N^i-1} 
\end{bmatrix}
=[
0 ,
1 ,
2 x_i, \dots  
(N^i-1)x_i^{N^i-1}
].
$$
That matrix containing powers of the $x_i$ is simply a Vandermonde matrix: a simple expression for its inverse is present in the literature [Eisenberg &Fedele, for example (2005)](http://wwwinfo.deis.unical.it/~fedele/research/pubs/FunSim.pdf).  With that in hand it is not difficult to show that 
$$
M_{ij} = 
\frac{T_{ij} }{S_{ij}}
$$

where
$$
T_{ij} =
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0 & : A_{ij}=0\\
e_{N^i-2}( \{ x_i-x_{\alpha^i_1}, ... , x_i-x_{\alpha^i_{N^i}}\} \setminus \{x_i-x_j\}) & : A_{ij}=1
\end{array}
\right. ,
$$

$$
S_{ij} = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1 & : A_{ij}=0\\
e_{N^i-1}( \{ x_j-x_{\alpha^i_1}, ... , x_j-x_{\alpha^i_{N^i}}\} ) & : A_{ij}=1
\end{array}
\right. ,
$$
for $e_k( \chi)$ the $k^{th}$ elementary symmetric polynomial of the set $\chi$,  and where $\chi_a \setminus \chi_b$ is the relative complement of $\chi_a$ with respect to $\chi_b$.

### Special Case: M Nilpotent

Here's an interesting special case.  If $A_{ij}=1 \; \forall \; i,j \in \{1, \dots, N\}$ then the definition of $M$ can be rewritten as 
$$
M V D=V D J
$$
where 
$$
J=
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 &\dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 &\dots & 0 \\
 \vdots &\vdots & \vdots &  \vdots  & \vdots \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &\dots & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &\dots & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix},
D=
\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{1}{0!} & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{1!} & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots &\vdots  \\ 
0 & 0 &\dots & \frac{1}{(N-2)!} & 0 \\
0 & 0 &\dots & 0 & \frac{1}{(N-1)!} \\
\end{bmatrix},
V=
\begin{bmatrix} 
x_1^0 & \dots &  x_1^{N-1} \\
 \vdots &  & \vdots \\ 
 x_N^0 & \dots & x_N^{N-1} 
\end{bmatrix}$$
It is not difficult to show that the product $V D$ is invertible, so $M$ is similar to $J$ which is, by examination, in Jordan normal form.  The eigenvalues can be read off the main diagonal of $J$: they're all zero, so $M$ is nilpotent.

### Specific Case: N=4 Non-Zero Pair of Eigenvalues

For the $N=5$ case where
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1&1 &1 &0 &0 \\
1&1 &1 &1 &0 \\
1 &1&1 &1 &1 \\
0 &1&1 &1 &1\\
0 &0&1 &1 &1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the characteristic polynomial is (via Mathematica)
$$
-\lambda^5 -\lambda^3  \frac{(x_1-x_4)+(x_1-x_5)+(x_2-x_5)}{(x_1-x_4)(x_1-x_5)(x_2-x_5)}
$$
(that non-zero coefficient is just $Tr[-\frac12 M^2]$.  The eigenvalues are $\{0^{\times 3}, \pm b \}$ for $b$ real or imaginary, depending on how the $x_i$ are ordered.  Obtaining analytic solutions is possible using Mathematica, but only for sufficiently small problems: $N<6$ on my computer.

I have not yet seen a case for which the eigenvalues of $M$ deviate from the pattern $\{0^{\times N-2}, \pm b \}$, hence I hypothesize that they never do.